# Prestashop, order product from supplier

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

In a new Prestashop installation I need to achieve on certain products, a on-hold status, meaning, for instance,

1. Some products are in stock ready to ship.
2. Other products must be ordered and will take 1 or 2 weeks to be delivered.

I've seen web stores where this info is displayed, my question is the following, is there a module that enbales this possibility? For instance, automaticly split the order with ready to stock items and order from supplier items?

Thanks,
Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

Prestashop already has this functionality, so no need for a module.

On the admin page, click on catalog->products. Then click the edit button for the product you want to change (should look like a paper and pencil). Click on the quantities tab, and then select 'Allow orders' under 'When out of stock'. You can then provide the message you want the user to see when the product is in stock, and the message they see when it's out of stock at the bottom of the page. Hit save you're done, at least for that product.